# How to automate visualization of S3 objects by using Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

The thing is that I have these objects in my S3 bucket (email) and I want to be able to visualize them since they're not that easy to open them and if you want to you need to manually do it. I was told there was a way to use Lambda function with S3 to be able to create a some kind of html view page to see the objects.

Hope someone can help me do that.

Comment: What type of files are they? What do you consider to be "visualization"? Please Edit your question to add more details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have provided, Here's what I understand.

1. You've email(s) in S3
2. You want to visualize/read them via website

There are many ways to do it. Simplest of all is using s3's public hosting capability. See [this AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html) for step by step details.

This example assumes your email is in `.txt` format. If you have any other formt (e.g. pdf / eml etc) you will need corresponding parser library and logic to open and read those. In that case this example may not work. you may want to look at other aws options such as [aws lightsail](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/resources/) or [aws amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/), It will depend on your requirements.

Based [on AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html), Here's what you can do at a high-level.

1. Create a basic `index.html` and upload to s3 folder.
2. Create a basic `error.html` and upload to your s3 folder.
3. Under bucket URL -> properties  edit and enable  'Static Website Hosting'
   e.g. https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/yours3bucket?region=us-west-1&tab=properties

This will give you an website URL something like below.

```
http://yours3bucket.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

4. Under bucket URL -> permissions , UnCheck "Block all public access".
   ***[ caution: this will open your s3 bucket to the world. For better access control, consider using IAM ]***
5. Add a bucket policy.
   ***[This example shows policy to enable access to anyone. you should consider restricting to certain users using IAM]***

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::yours3bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

After that, simply launch your  static website
http://yours3bucket.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/index.html

Each of your email (assuming its in text format) should be accessible as below.

http://yours3bucket.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/youremailobject.txt

Here's how it looks at my end
[image]